# How did Laura make that edit?

Tags: support

I found this [edit](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/976/3) to be somewhat surprising. Had there been a ♦ (moderator diamond) besides her name it wouldn't have been.

She doesn't *seem* to be a moderator and doesn't have 1000>= reps, required to make edits in meta since edits can't be suggested there, with an exception of [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

So how did she make that edit?

I see her profile says:

> PM @ Stack Exchange.

But don't SE employees and Community Manager get mod diamond by their name? Can only guess what *PM* means?

Comment: She *is* [employed by Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) (the PM presumably stands for [Associate] Product Manager, which is her title).  Can't speak for the actual edit privileges and lack of a diamond though.

Comment: @goldPseudo, your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @Kaveh It doesn't really answer the question, though.  I'm pretty much in the same boat OP is on this question; I didn't realize non-diamond staff had network-wide edit privileges (assuming that's what's happening here), and have no clue what, if any, other privileges they may have.

Comment: @goldPseudo, they do have access to the software, they can do way more than you can imagine. But you can ping Anna or Robert in the teacher's lounge so someone from SE can post an authoritative answer.

Comment: There could be one possibility. She wore the diamond to make that edit and then took it off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laura is a Product Manager at Stack Exchange and therefore *could* have a diamond on every site (and each meta). For a variety of reasons, some employees chose *not* to have a diamond on every site. However, employees have special privileges on per-site-metas to [edit and tag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193587/1438) whether they have a diamond or not. The primary reason for this is for exactly the situation mentioned in the question. Rather than a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) the question was a [support](/questions/tagged/support) post. As a practical matter, Laura keeps tabs on feature requests as a part of her job. Community Managers, such as myself try to make sure support questions are satisfactorily answered. (Which, by the way, is why I'm answering this question. ;-)